# Is there an alternative or adjustment for my View to make it lighter and consumes less RAM?

Tags: swiftui

I have this View below which I looped with ForEach for 15 times inside a ScrollView in my main view, but I noticed that the app consumed more extra 58MB of RAM which I believe is a bit heavy for just these views. I am looking for alternative ways or adjustments for the View below to make it lighter.

```
VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 0) {
            Spacer()
            Text("Like")
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
            Text("Comment")
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
            Text("Share")
                .padding(.vertical, 2)
            Spacer()
        }
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            Text("Hey guys how is going?")
                .font(.system(.headline))
                .padding(.vertical)
                .padding(.trailing, 15)
                .lineLimit(1)
            HStack {
                Text("describtion")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .padding(.bottom)
                Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    Image(systemName: "cloud.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                        .foregroundColor(.purple)
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
                .padding(.trailing, 25)
            }
        }
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding(.bottom)
```

Comment: Even with VStack at root of ScrollView I see only 16MB with provided code in ForEach, so I assume it is in different code. Anyway, use LazyVStack to avoid loading all views at one time.

Comment: I’ll try your suggestion. Appreciated.